# ADF pipeline task if condition expression getting error function 'and' does not accept 5 argument(s)

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my adf pipeline I have on if condition so I am trying to run expression
@and(or(or(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '01'),equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '02')),or(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '03'),equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '04'))),startswith(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dddd'), 'Wednesday'),equals(variables('envName'), 'dev'),greaterOrEquals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd'), '07'),lessOrEquals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd'), '13')) but it is not working as expected.

I want to check if the current month is jan,feb,mar&april if current month is this then check the date is between 7 to 13 if the date is between 7-13 then check the day is Wednesday and eenv is dev if condition true then it will execute if otherwise it will go into else

I tried with different condition but getting error that function and not support 4 argument or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

`And` and `or` accept only 2 arguments at a single time, so modify the expression like below.

```
@and(
    or(
        equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '01'),
        or(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '02'),
        or(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '03'),
        equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MM'), '04')))
    ),
    and(greaterOrEquals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd'), '07'),
    and(lessOrEquals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dd'), '13'),
    and(startsWith(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'dddd'), 'Wednesday'),
    equals(variables('envName'), 'dev'))))
)
```

Output:

Below are the default variables.

[image]

After execution.

[image]

For more information check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#and) documentation.